# How to pass the table cell value via ajax to php

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I want to when i click table that cell value pass to php via ajax show that value in alert box. I wrote code but its show alert box value like [object HTMLTableCellElement]..

Anyone help,

Here my code:

```js
function found(row) {
     
     var table=document.getElementById("table");
     var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
     for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  rows[i].onclick = (function() {
            
            return function() {
             var result = this.cells[1];
             var plate  = this.cells[6];
             var km  =  this.cells[7];
             var dataString = 'plate=' + plate + '&km='+km;
             $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'km.php',
                async: true,
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                global: false,
                success: function(result) {
                 alert("succ : " + result);
                   
                }
            });
             
            }    
        })(i);
    }
 }
```

My php:

```js
<?php
$plate = $_POST['plate'];
$km = $_POST['km'];
echo $plate;
echo $km;

?>
```

Comment: post your html please

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the variables to the table cell elements, not the text in them.

```
var result = this.cells[1].textContent;
var plate = this.cells[6].textContent;
var km = this.cells[7].textContent;
```

BTW, there doesn't seem to be a need to use the IIFE pattern around your `onclick` function. That's only needed if the function refers to `i`, but it doesn't.

BTW, you can write the whole thing more succinctly using jQuery:

```
$("#table tr").click(function() {
    var cells = $(this).find('td');
    var result = cells.eq(1).text(); // This isn't used?
    var plate = cells.eq(6).text();
    var km = cells.eq(7).text();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'km.php',
        async: true,
        data: {plate: plate, km: km},
        cache: false,
        global: false,
        success: function(result) {
            alert("succ : " + result);

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Then how.. Can you tell

Comment: What are you trying to ask?

Comment: @appu It's right there in the answer... And you should not bind an event handler for every row, you only need one.

Comment: @jeroen There's nothing wrong with binding an event handler for each row.

Comment: There doesn't seem any reason to do that here (the loop), `this` will be the clicked row either way.

Comment: What should he bind the handler to instead of the row? If he binds it to the table, `this` will be the table, not the current row.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, it's the mix of plain js and jQuery that got me confused. I would have used something like `$('table').on('click', 'tr', ...` instead: All jQuery or none at all, for the values too.

Comment: I need replace alert box to confirm box.. If i click OK means call another function... How to do

Comment: `if (confirm("succ: " + result)) { anotherFunction(result)); }`